# Error: Could not be modified to add a 'DbSet<..> property to it - MVC4 & EF 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

Working on ASP.NET MVC 4 and I have created separate class library for Entity Framework 5 project 
I have added a reference to that EF project (class library) into my MVC Web project..

EF: Working with `Schema First` approach that pulls all my tables to my `.EDMX`.

```
EFModel.edmx :=>
           EFModel.tt
                  >>>Address.cs
                  >>>Requester.cs <<<=== (I'm working on this particular model object)     
                  <<<More...>>>
```

sample Requester.cs auto-generated code template:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//    This code was generated from a template.
//
//    Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//    Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace issoa_ef
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class requester
    {
        public requester()
        {
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Active { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CreatedById { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ModifiedId { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedDateTime { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Back To MVC Project:

```
MVC==> Model==> Folder
```

I have created a model class for the `Requester` but shorter version, the reason I have created in the MVC Model folder so that I can have my data annotation and decorate data attribute to my prop.

Requester.cs

```
namespace issoa_mvc.Models
{
    public class Requesters 
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Active { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Creating `Scaffolding` for the Requester

[image: Error Message]

Error Screen:

[image: Scaffolding Selection]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to scaffold a user-defined class that is not included in the specified DbContext - there's nothing else to it.

If you want to decorate the auto-generated class, you need to implement a class for the metadata, then decorate the auto-generated class (via partial implementation) using the `MetadataType` attribute.  Then choose the original auto-generated class as the Model class.  Refer to [MetadataType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute.aspx) (sample usage at the bottom)